# Is $X^5+Y^5-1$ irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

I would really just like a hint or a nudge in the right direction. I feel pretty comfortable with irreducibility over a single variable, but I haven't been exposed to many multivariable questions.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: see it as $f(X)\in (\Bbb C[Y])[X]$ and apply Eisenstein with the prime $Y-1$.

Comment: So $X^5+Y^5-1=X^5+(Y^4+Y^3+Y^2+Y+1)(Y-1)$. Since $Y-1$ is prime in $\mathbb{C}[Y]$, prime because irreducible in a UFD, the ideal (Y-1) is a prime ideal, and therefore $(Y^4+Y^3+Y^2+Y+1)(Y-1)\in (Y-1)$, but it is not contained in ( (Y-1) )^2. Therefore by Eisenstein $X^5+Y^5-1$ is irreducible over $(\mathbb{C}[Y])[X]=\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$.